# Cómo ocultar un div usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

quiero ocultar un div usando un boton, y a la misma vez que vuelva aparecer al volver a hacer click en el.

```
<div id='ocultar-y-mostrar'>CONTENIDO</div>

<button id='ocultar-mostrar'><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
```

**¿Cómo lo hago?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Clickeame</button>

<div id="myDIV" style="border:1px solid black;">
  Este elemento aparece y desaparece con el botón
</div>
```

Comment: Sabes cómo hago para que el div también desaparezca haciendo click en cualquier parte de la página?

Comment: ¿como un tipo modal? Si usas jquery puedes basarte en esta respuesta de SOen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457246/jquery-click-function-exclude-children cambiando el `$(".example")` por `$(document)` o el `div` contenedor de tu html y agregando el código de mostrar/ocultar

Answer (score 4):

Hola que tal buscando en la web encontre como hacerlos con js:

```
document.getElementById("ID_DEL_ELEMENTO").style.display = "none";
```

Con JQuery puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
$("#ID_DEL_ELEMENTO").hide();
```

Comment: si lo encontraste en la web, conviene que añadas como créditos al autor la página de donde lo sacaste

Answer (score 2):

Tambien puedes usar la propiedad de css **visibility** y camiarlo con **javascript**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='ocultar-y-mostrar'>CONTENIDO</div>

    <button id='ocultar-mostrar'><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>ocultar/mostrar</button>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        function init() {
            let div = document.querySelector('#ocultar-y-mostrar');
            div.style.visibility = 'visible';
            let boton = document.querySelector('#ocultar-mostrar');
            boton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                if(div.style.visibility === 'visible'){
                    div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }else{
                    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
                }
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!
Yo lo necesitaba simplemente para mostrar más texto y lo resolví así:

```
Contenido visible. <div id='leer_mas'><a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById("contenido").style.display = "block"; document.getElementById("leer_mas").style.display = "none";'>Leer más</a></div>
<div id='contenido' style="display: none;">
Contenido oculto
</div>
```

Comment: Contenido visible. <div id='leer_mas'><a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById("contenido").style.display = "block"; document.getElementById("leer_mas").style.display = "none";'>Leer más</a></div>
<div id='contenido' style="display: none;">
Contenido oculto
</div>

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tu código, para darle formato. Luego, no olvides borrar tu comentario. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.