# Cómo hago para que aparezca oculto por defecto el div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, div

Tengo el siguiente código pero necesito que aparezca oculto por defecto, es decir que al presionar el botón me muestre el lorem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="return mostrarOcultar('ocultable')" type="button" >Mostrar/Ocultar</button>

    <div id="ocultable" >Soy un texto ocultable.</div>

    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, numquam ut iusto ab. Odit nemo minus accusantium fugiat commodi cumque, adipisci aperiam ipsum, tempora, voluptatibus sequi? Labore necessitatibus quibusdam in!
    </div>

    <script>
        function mostrarOcultar(id){
            var elemento = document.getElementById(id);

            if (elemento.style.display == "none") {
                elemento.style.display = "block"
            } else {
                elemento.style.display = "none"
            };
            return true;

            if(!elemento) {
                return true;
            }
        };

    //Ocultar/Mostrar Div's

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Con Javascript? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220253/c%C3%B3mo-ocultar-un-div-usando-javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
//oculto por defecto
element = document.getElementById('ocultable');
element.style.display = 'none';  

function mostrarOcultar(){
  element = document.getElementById('ocultable');
  estado = element.style.display;
  if(estado == 'none'){
  element.style.display='block'
  }else{
  element.style.display = 'none'; 
  }

}//end function mostrarOcultar
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrarOcultar();" type="button" >Mostrar/Ocultar</button>

<div id="ocultable">Soy un texto ocultable.</div>

<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, numquam ut iusto ab. Odit nemo minus accusantium fugiat commodi cumque, adipisci aperiam ipsum, tempora, voluptatibus sequi? Labore necessitatibus quibusdam in!
</div>
```

Si te fijas por defecto oculto tu div con id 'ocultable', y en un if valido el estado, espero te sirva suerte..!!

Comment: gracias eso era!

Answer (score 0):

Agregale al `div` un estilo por defecto

```html
<div id="ocultable" style="display:none" >Soy un texto ocultable.</div>
```

o simplemente desde un estilo por `css`

```css
#ocultable{
 display: none
}
```

o cuando cargue el documento por medio de `JavaScript`

```js
window.onload = function(){
  documento.getElementById('ocultable').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer algo como esto el el javascript**

```js
function mostrarOcultar() {
  document.getElementById('ocultable').classList.toggle("ocultable");
}
```

```css
.ocultable {
  display: none;
}
.negro {
border: 7px black double;
}
* {
font-family:"Century Gothic";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrarOcultar()">Ocultar/Mostrar</button>
<div id="ocultable" class="ocultable">
  <h1>Hola yo me oculto y aparezco</h1>
  </div>
  
  <h1 class="negro">Así de facil</h1>
```